# Can you find the pattern? What two letters are missing from this sequence?

Tags: pattern, knowledge

What are the two missing letters in the sequence below?

JT SH PM JC KC __ JT

Hint:

> Sometimes backwards is easier than forwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the two missing letters in the sequence below?

> BM the initials of the 18th Canadian Prime Minister Brian Mulroney

Sometimes backwards is easier than forwards:

> The letters are a list of initials fom Canadian Prime Ministers starting from Justin Trudeau and going backwards all the way to John Turner